# How to display a slideshow of images from a mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a table named `images`, the fields are `id, name, photo`, the `photo` field is `varchar` as the pictures are stored onto the server using a php form. At the minute my code displays only 1 image from the table, please could someone help me so that it does a slideshow of all the images with the query:

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE name='$pagetitle'
```

`$pagetitle` is defined elsewhere in the script.

The problem is within the index.php file

### index.php

```html
<!-- Image Slide Show Start -->
      
      <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
      <img align="middle" src="" name="slide" border=0 width=300 height=375>
    

<?php 
require('mysqli.php');
$data = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE name= '$pagetitle'");
$image = mysqli_fetch_array( $data );

$directory = ("/images/".$image['photo'] . "");

$conn->close();

?>    
<script>


//configure the paths of the images, plus corresponding target links
slideshowimages("<?php echo $directory ?>")

//configure the speed of the slideshow, in miliseconds
var slideshowspeed=2000

var whichlink=0
var whichimage=0
function slideit(){
if (!document.images)
return
document.images.slide.src=slideimages[whichimage].src
whichlink=whichimage
if (whichimage<slideimages.length-1)
whichimage++
else
whichimage=0
setTimeout("slideit()",slideshowspeed)
}
slideit()


</script> </div><br><br>
      <!-- Image Slide Show End -->
```

Comment: First glance and it looks as though you're using both the obsolete `mysql_` extension and `mysqli_`

Comment: What does the function `slideshowimages` do? How many records are returned by the query?

Comment: i dont think that is the problem, because in the source code the php is only putting 1 image into the slideshowimages function. Which is the root of the images to be displayed in the slideshow. If i took the php out and put images from a folder in there, the js works fine.

Comment: There's probably a bit too much going on here for a single, definitive answer - try breaking it down into smaller problems; how to connect to the database (`mysqli_` or `pdo`) and retrieve the data, which slideshow plugin to use (personally I tend to use *unslider* http://unslider.com/) or whether to write one from scratch (not really worth it nowadays)... currently it does look like you've grabbed code from here and you're trying to hammer it all together without really understanding it... learn to walk before you try running ;)

Comment: As i said above, most of the code is working, its just the javascript think its should only show 1 picture, something isn't matching up in the index.php file.

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: thanks, i have changed it to mysqli.

Comment: Is this issue withing the `slideshowimages("<?php echo $directory ?>") ` line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The solved code is below:**

```html
<?php

// Connect to the database
       require('mysqli.php');
        
// Query for a list of all existing files

$sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE name= '$pagetitle'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$directory = '';
while( $image = $result->fetch_assoc() )
    $directory .= ($directory != '' ? "," : '') . ('"/images/'.$image["photo"] . '"');



// Check if it was successfull
 if($directory != '') {
  
    // if there are images for this page, run the javascript
 ?><script>


 //configure the paths of the images, plus corresponding target links   
 slideshowimages(<?php print $directory ?>)

 //configure the speed of the slideshow, in miliseconds
 var slideshowspeed=2000

 var whichlink=0
 var whichimage=0
 function slideit(){
 if (!document.images)
 return
 document.images.slide.src=slideimages[whichimage].src
 whichlink=whichimage
 if (whichimage<slideimages.length-1)
 whichimage++
 else
 whichimage=0
 setTimeout("slideit()",slideshowspeed)
 }
 slideit()


 </script>
 <?
   }  else {
        // If there are not any images for this page, leave the space blank
        echo "";
  } 
 
// Close the mysql connection
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//Make connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//SQL query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dir= "" . $row["field"]. "";
       echo" <div class='content section' style='max-width:500px'>
             <img class='slides' src='$dir' style=width:100%></div>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Empty Gallery";
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<script>
var index = 0;
slideshow();
function slideshow() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  index++;
  if (index > x.length) {index = 1}    
  x[index-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(slideshow, 3000); // Change slides every 3 seconds
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```